# Configuring Apache with Django

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to configure Apache with Django. Everything is working except the admin panel. It's static files are not loading. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files) talks about different ways of doing it but none are working for me.

Here is my 0000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin maahd@meddy.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

Alias /static /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static        

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
include sites-available/meddy.co.conf
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Here is my meddy.co.conf where meddy.co is my website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ec2-54-254-141-40.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
        ServerAlias www.ec2-54-254-141-40.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy.wsgi

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sp-django-master

    #Alias /static /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static

    <Location "/static/">
            Options -Indexes
        </Location>

    #AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static/meddy1/css/$1

    AliasMatch ^/([^/meddy1]*\.css) /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static/meddy1/css/$1
    AliasMatch ^/([^/admin]*\.css) /var/www/html/sp-django-master/static/admin/css/$1   

    Alias /static/ /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static/

    <Directory /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/sp-django-master/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /var/www/html/sp-django-master/uploads/

        <Directory /var/www/html/sp-django-master/uploads>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

    Alias /static/admin/ /var/www/html/sp-django-master/static/admin/

</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you have ran `collectstatic` and you see the files have been copied to `/var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static`? Have you checked the permissions on these files (check if a temporary `chmod 777` fixes things to check this). What do you have in your Django settings for `STATIC_ROOT`?

Comment: figured it out and posted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You don't need the second last line: `Alias /static/admin/ /var/www/html/sp-django-master/static/admin/` since it forces django to look for static files in another folder when django should be looking in the static folder in the app root. So just use `Alias /static/ /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static/`. Since I was using collectstatic, I didn't have to distinguish between `static/admin/` and `static/`